# Get a text value for DOM and display in dat.gui field

Tags: javascript, html, dat.gui

I have a dat.gui to control a three.js scene. I want it to display a text value from the DOM

```
 <div id="data">data</div>
```

I can't see a way to get this to work. Could you please help me out?
Thank you very much

```
var guiControls = new function() {
    this.message = document.getElementById('data');

var gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(guiControls, 'message')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
this.message = document.getElementById('data').value;
```

Use:

```
this.message = document.getElementById('distance').textContent;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know how can i get it to update when the DOM element changes?

Comment: Add the "onchange" event listener to the div:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange

Comment: I've refered your link but I can't figure out how to address the element inside dat.gui could you please help me out? I can't ask another question for 90 mins.

Comment: How can i directly address da.gui 'message' field like this? `let log = document.getElementById('log');`

Comment: I understand your question now, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with the dat.gui library.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `querySelector` to fetch the data from any html element. MDN documentation says querySelector is prefer.

**Benefits:**

- QuerySelector is the newer feature.
- QuerySelector is better supported than getElementsByClassName.

How to use:

```
document.querySelector("#data").innerText
```